# How to restrict content inappropriate for children on the Android Kindle app?

Tags: parental-control, kindle-for-android

Google play books, and Amazon devices like the Kindle, have parental controls that allow parents to stop their children from downloading explicit sexual/violent books and comics.

But the Android Kindle App does not seem to have any. (Despite being a far more popular way for children to read books than either of the above).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

(I googled a lot but only got useless info: instructions for how to do it on Kindle Fire or other Kindle hardware; a family feature on Amazon https://parents.amazon.com.au/ to which you can add neither your kids Android devices nor their accounts; etc).

Comment: From what I can tell the feature you desire is [Amazon Household](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GXULX24SE2RD7EXS) which would require separate accounts, however it doesn't appear to be available in Australia (from what I can gather).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this has some parental control features, yes. But I get "Your account is ineligible to add a teen". No explanation, but as you say, it looks like it's region locked. Once again a major tech company fails to understand the basics of the internet and restricts critical features to USA only for absolutely no reason at all. :(